# Please identify this tree

Tags: identification

[image]

Found on the island of Kauai in December

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is *Ardisia elliptica*, a native of southeast Asia and introduced in many tropical regions.

http://luirig.altervista.org/pics/index3.php?search=shoebutton+ardisia&page=1

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Java Plum; Syzygium cumini. [Java Plum](http://the3foragers.blogspot.com/2012/01/)  Did you taste these berries?  Don't think I would have until I knew for sure.  Hope this is close!